# CSV - not uploading all records

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I'm trying to parse a small CSV file and insert the records into MySQL.

The problem I'm having is that the CSV has 150 rows, but only 2 seem to be inserted:

```
        $file = new SplFileObject($uploadedFile);

        $separator = ',';
        $rowCounter = 1;
        $errors = array();

        $fh = fopen($uploadedFile, 'r');
        if(!$fh) die('File no good!');

        // Get headings
        $headings = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ',');
        $num_cols = count($headings);
        $num_rows = 1;

        // Read the file as csv
        while ($row = $file->fgetcsv($separator)) {

            //missed product if num columns in this row not the same as num headings
            if (count($row) != $num_cols) {
                $row = array_pad($row, $num_cols, NULL);
            }

            for ($i=0; $i<count($headings); $i++) {
                $raw_prod[$headings[$i]] = $row[$i];
            }

             $item = new Item();
             $item->name = $raw_prod['NAME'];
             $item->age = $raw_prod['AGE'];
             $item->location = $raw_prod['LOCATION'];
             $item->save();
         }
```

If I `var_dump($item)` I get all 150 records, but only 2 ever get inserted.

I just don't understand why this is happening

Thanks

Comment: Near the end you are using the `$data_row` array but I don't see where that gets defined or populated.

Comment: Updated to use `$raw_prod`

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
while ($row = $file->fgetcsv($separator)) {
```

should be

```
while (($row = $file->fgetcsv($separator)) !== false) {
```

Comment: Adding that check in still inserts 2 rows, but kills my page